# How to save and restore view

Tags: javascript

After I open and close a modal page, the view switches to the top left.
It only happens on some browser (example, Chrome when emulating a Galaxy S5 phone).

I need to save the view before opening the modal page, and restore it after closing the modal page.

How do I do it?

I'm not asking for a fix to my code. I cannot find what are the functions used in Javascript to set and save the view, and that is what I'm asking for.
This should be a common problem, but I do not know the keywords used to search the answer by myself. I tried to search "save" and "restore" "view" in "javascript", but I get nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @FrankerZ I do not ask for a fix to my code. I ask for what are the functions generally used to save and restore the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

1-Save the posicion of the scrollbar

```
var PosicionScrollbar = $(window).scrollTop();
```

2-Then restore

```
$(window).scrollTop(PosicionScrollbar);
```